# How can I update the look of my Android app?

Tags: android, user-interface, sdk, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I have got an Android app that I built a while ago and that was built for Android 2.3.3. The problem is that i looks very clunky as it uses those old 2.3.3 buttons and text edits.

My question: Is it possible to change the look to Android 4.0? I mean, can I update the app so that it looks different by just making minor tweaks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try [HoloEverywhere](https://github.com/ChristopheVersieux/HoloEverywhere). It brings the default Holo dark/light Theme to Devices with Android 2.1 to 2.3 .

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can updated your application & use various theme given by Android SDK.For More Information [Read This Link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `Theme.DeviceDefault` for your theme. This will make your app to use Android 4.0 theme on devices with Android 4.